# Define function in Haskell with computations in arguments

Tags: haskell

How can I define a function in Haskell like this:

```
x(0)     = 1
x(2*k)   = sin(k) * cos(k)
x(2*k+1) = cos(k/2) - tan(2*k)
```

Haskell does not allow to define a function with computation in its arguments. It will raise a "Parse error in pattern" error.

If I try to define everything in terms of `x(k)`, like this:

```
x(k) = sin(k/2) * cos(k/2)
x(k) = cos((k/2-1)/2) - tan(k/2-1)
```

I will have two definitions for `x(k)`, which is not valid.

Comment: You forget that *any* number `k` can be described as `2*k+1`! Plus `n+k` patterns are disabled by default, and `n*k` patterns don't exist, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define this as follows:

```
f 0 = 1
f i | even i = sin(k) * cos(k)
    | otherwise = cos(k/2) - tan(2*k)
    where k = fromIntegral $ div i 2
```

I replaced `x` by `f` because `x` looks more like a *variable* than a function. Furthermore I used `i` as the incoming parameter.

`div i 2` means you divide `i` by `2` (and floor the result), such that `0` maps to `0`, `1` to `0` and `2` to `1`. Then one can use `fromIntegral` to convert it to a `Floating`; otherwise you cannot take the `sin`, etc.

Now there are two cases (except from the `f 0` case): the one where `i` is `even` (`2*k`) and the one where `i` is `odd` (in this case `otherwise`). You can use [guards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27609172/67579) for this. For the even case, we now use `sin(k) * cos(k)` and for the other one `cos(k/2)-tan(2*k)`. Note that for the `k/2` we use a floating point, so if `i` is `7`, `k` will be `3` and you will thus calculate the `cos(1.5)-tan(6)`.